# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserId'

Tags: c#, sql-insert, sqldatasource

I am getting this exception and can not figure out why: `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserId'`

This is my code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="FirstNameBox" runat="server" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="LastNameBox" runat="server" />
<asp:SqlDataSource
    ID="InsertText"
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO UserForm (UserId,FirstName,LastName) VALUES  (@UserId,@FiName,@LaName)">

   <InsertParameters>
      <asp:ControlParameter Name="FiName" ControlID="FirstNameBox" PropertyName="Text" />
      <asp:ControlParameter Name="LaName" ControlID="LastNameBox" PropertyName="Text" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" />
   </InsertParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is what I have in my code behind file:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   InsertText.Insert();
}
```

Comment: There must be more in your code behind file... where are you declaring the parameters you are trying to pass, for example?

Comment: The error message says it all really. The table requires than you supply a value for UserID, which you haven't.

Comment: You set Fname and Lname, but nowhere do you seem to be setting the userID, hence the null exception.

Comment: easiest way to avoid this is to auto-increment a unique non-null userid field.  Unless your userids are meaningful (employee #).

Comment: Possibly because the database has a constraint on the table that a UserId is required (thus cannot be null) ...???

Comment: I set the UserId Column to be the primary and foreign key. I set the UserId to be the GUID. When I checked the table the UserId is already there. I just want to add a users first or last name.

Comment: @DarrellGadson - Then you don't want to `INSERT`, you want to `UPDATE`.  And in that case, you need to know what the `UserId` of the record you want to update is, and pass that back.

Comment: @Bobson - So use the UpdateCommand and I need to grab the UserId by using the MembershipUser.ProviderUserKey Property in order to identify the current user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just grabbed the userid and performed an update command.

```
Guid userGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;

UserIdLabel.Text = userGuid.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently you have set your table in way, that you HAVE TO supply a value for UserId. If that isn't an intended behavior, I'd suggest to change the column in SQL server to auto-incremented...

It should look like this for instance:

```
[UserId]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL
```

EDIT based on comments:

> I set the UserId Column to be the primary and foreign key. I set the
>   UserId to be the GUID. When I checked the table the UserId is already
>   there. I just want to add a users first or last name.

Not sure what's your problem then, first you're talking about `INSERT`, now you're talking about setting values for the existing record. If you want to `update` the existing record, you need to get the id first and update the values accordingly

An example SQL command may look similar to this:

```
UPDATE UserForm SET FirstName = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName WHERE UserId = @UserId
```

Insert does what it says - inserts a new record to the table.

Comment: I tried to use an UpdateCommand. I don't get an exception but the table is not updated.

Answer (score 2):

you do not set any value for the userId column. if it already has been set identity. you can remove the userid when you insert the data.