# Cannot insert the value NULL into column in ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

When trying to use this code:

```
var model = new MasterEntities();

var customer = new Customers();
customer.Sessionid = 25641;

model.Customers.Add(customer);
model.SaveChanges();
```

I get:

> {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Sessionid', table
>   'master.dbo.Column'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

The column "Sessionid" is actually the primary key and is marked with [KEY] like this:

```
 public class Customers
    {   
        [Key]
        public long Sessionid { get; set; }
        public long? Pers { get; set; }
    }
```

So according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470736/cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-roleid-mvc4-simple-membership) question, it seems as if when the property is marked with `[KEY]`, EF ignores my own declaration of Sessionid since it expects the database to assign the value.

So how can I solve this? If I remove `[KEY]` I get the `"entity type has no key defined"` exception...

Comment: Is your table *actually* called `Column`? And in the `master` database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Entity Framework Code First CTP5, how do I create a primary key column that are INTs and are not identity columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999853/using-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-how-do-i-create-a-primary-key-column-tha)

Comment: Maybe your SessionID has autoIncrement?

Comment: I agree with @Martin.I think something went wrong when mapping database and classes.

Comment: No @MartinSmith it's not :) I just edited it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I solved it by adding `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` like this:

```
public class Customers
    {   
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public long Sessionid { get; set; }
        public long? Pers { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I can not find out dll for DatabaseGenerated

Comment: @JohnNguyen `DatabaseGenerated` and `DatabaseGeneratedOption` are both in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` namespace, which is part of EntityFramework. Make sure you have a reference to EF or have the EF NuGet package installed.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you sir! Been trying different variations of this for 4 hours until I came across your excellent solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can configure SQL to auto-generate (and auto-increment) the primary key for the table upon inserts. Then just remove the [Key] in C# and you don't need to set the ID in the application manually, the db will generate it for you.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would like to do that? From a design point of view, that is not 'generally' the norm - you can still let SQL generate a generic ID column as the pKey and set your own 'sessionID' manually as though it were a regular (non-key) column..?

Comment: yes there is a specific reason :) But too difficult to get into that here in a comment :)

Comment: Sounds like the kind of thing Dean Varillas would often do.. led me to quit.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this problem multiple times while working with `Microsoft SQL Server` and I have followed the same way to fix it. To solve this problem, make sure **Identity Specification** is set to **Yes**. Here's how it looks like:

[image: Identity Specification]

In this way the column number *auto increments* as a primary key normally would.

**HOW?:** *right-click* the table that contains the column, choose *Design*, *select* the primary key and in *Column Properties* window find **Identity Specification** and set it to **Yes**.