# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'XXX' (Entity framework)

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I tried to add object through, it throws error as above. My ID column is `NOT NULL` and without `Identity`. My code is like below. I am assigning value to ID as well.

I have added attribute `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` for this property in context class as per [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727337/cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-in-asp-net-mvc-entity-framework) but does not work.

```
  int id = context.CreditApps.Max(x => x.ID);
                    if (id != null && id != 0)
                    {
                        newCreditAppId = id + 1;
                        objCredit.ID = newCreditAppId;
                    }

                    objCredit.IsActive = true;
                    context.DTOriginalCreditApps.AddObject(objCredit);
                    context.SaveChanges();
```

Context class

```
#region Primitive Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] //Added later
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _Id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Id != value)
            {
                OnIdChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("Id");
                _Id = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("Id");
                OnIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what happens if id == 0 : `if (id != null && id != 0)`, what else ?

Comment: It is not of use. It comes in if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change attribute `StoreGeneratedPattern="None"` of ID column of the mentioned entity in the XML SSDL of edmx file.

Basically this runtime exception occur when your table doesn't contain primary key without identity.