# Repository/UnitOfWork Add throws Cannot insert the value NULL into column error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, repository-pattern, n-tier-architecture

I am working on an application that GETs data from a REST API. I am parsing the json against a concrete class and then stepping through that piece to either `Update` or `Insert` (depending of if the row exists) into a SQL database. Part of this is creating a Unique Identifier column with an `SkillId` and an `AccountId`, aptly named `AccountSkillId`. I believe I have traced the issue to my `Add` portion of my `Repository` because the `Commit` works, but the `Add` does not.

The `Add` acts like the entity that I am passing is empty, but when I look at it in the locals it shows that it is not empty:

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the Code in my Business Layer that attempts

```
    public void GetSkills()
    {
        var dataContext = new LivePersonContext(ConfigurationWrapper.DataConnectionString);
        var apiRequest = new OAuthRequest();
        var builder = new StringBuilder("");

        using (dataContext)
        {
            var uow = new UnitOfWork(dataContext);
            var accountCredentialIds = uow.Accounts.GetAll().Select(c => c.AccountID).ToList();

            foreach (var a in accountCredentialIds)
            {
                var account = a;
                try
                {
                    builder.Clear();
                    var consumerKey = uow.Accounts.GetById(account).ConsumerKey;
                    var consumerSecret = uow.Accounts.GetById(account).ConsumerSecret;
                    var token = uow.Accounts.GetById(account).Token;
                    var tokenSecret = uow.Accounts.GetById(account).TokenSecret;
                    builder.AppendFormat(ConfigurationWrapper.SkillsUri, account);
                    var uri = builder.ToString();

                    var response = apiRequest.OauthRequestResponse(uri, consumerKey, consumerSecret, token,
                        tokenSecret);
                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Entity.Skills>>(json);

                            var currentSkillData = uow.SkillMeta.GetAll().Select(c => c.AccountSkillId).ToList();

                            foreach (var item in jsonObj)
                            {
                                if (item.id != null)
                                {
                                    var itemId = int.Parse(item.id);
                                    var string2 = item.id + account;


                                    var accountSkillId = int.Parse(string2);

                                    if (currentSkillData.Contains(accountSkillId))
                                    {
                                        var skillUpdate = uow.SkillMeta.GetById(accountSkillId);

                                       // skillUpdate.AccountSkillID = int.Parse(accountSkillId);
                                        //skillUpdate.AccountID = account;
                                        //skillUpdate.SkillID = int.Parse(item.id);
                                        skillUpdate.Name = item.name;
                                        skillUpdate.IsDefault = item.isDefault;
                                        skillUpdate.Description = item.description;
                                        uow.Commit();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        var addSkill = new lp_Skill_Meta
                                        {
                                            AccountSkillId = accountSkillId,
                                            AccountId = account,
                                            SkillId = itemId,
                                            Name = item.name,
                                            IsDefault = item.isDefault,
                                            Description = item.description,

                                            //TODO: Verify that they are only ever passing single values
                                            Rel = item.links[0].rel,
                                            Href = item.links[0].href
                                        };


                                            uow.SkillMeta.Add(addSkill);
                                            uow.Commit();
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    var lEngine = new LoggerEngine{Logger = _logger};
                    lEngine.Log("ERROR: " + exception);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is look at my Repository Abstract Class

```
 public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : class
{
    protected  DbSet<T> _objectSet;

    public Repository(BaseContext context)
    {
        _objectSet = context.Set<T>();
    }
    #region IRepository<T> Members

    public abstract T GetById(object id);

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _objectSet;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>>  filter)
    {
        return _objectSet.Where(filter);
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _objectSet.Add(entity);

    }

    public void Remove(T entity)
    {
        _objectSet.Remove(entity);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

`BaseContext` is a `DbContext` Abstraction in my DAL

Here is my Entity that I am trying to Add into my DB

```
public class lp_Skill_Meta
{
    [Key]  
    public long AccountSkillId { get; set; }

    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Rel { get; set; }
    public string Href { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the schema of the DB:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[lp_Skill_Meta](
    [AccountSkillId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [AccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SkillId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [IsDefault] [bit] NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Rel] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Href] [varchar](250) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

As you can see in the picture the entity is not empty when I pass it into the add and try to commit the change. But I still get:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column `AccountSkillId`, table
>   `DatabaseName.dbo.lp_Skill_Meta'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

I have been staring at this for a few hours now and have searched and searched and did not see this situation (not saying it isn't there), but any help would be amazing.

**UPDATE:** Based off of a SQL Trace hat tip to Jeff below in the comments here is the query that EF is trying to run

> exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[lp_Skill]([AccountId], [SkillId],
>   [Name], [IsDefault], [Description], [Rel], [Href]) VALUES (@0, @1, @2,
>   @3, @4, @5, @6) SELECT [AccountSkillId] FROM [dbo].[lp_Skill] WHERE
>   @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND  [AccountSkillId] = scope_identity()' ,N'@0 int,@1
>   int,@2 nvarchar(max) ,@3 bit,@4 nvarchar(max) ,@5 nvarchar(max) ,@6
>   nvarchar(max) '
>   ,@0=10740014,@1=6,@2=N'Abusers',@3=0,@4=N'Abusers',@5=N'self',@6=N'https://sales.liveperson.net/api/account/10740014/skills/6'

AccountSkillId is not an identity column in the DB so this why its throwing the NULL. Now on to the search on how to get it to stop marking that column as an Identity...

Comment: it's complaining column AccountSkillId is null, maybe set a breakpoint before saving to make sure that field is not null

Comment: Yeah I added a var check = addSkill.AccountSkillId and it shows the appropriate AccountSkillId. That's why its so confusing that its not working because the entity is not empty, and it shouldnt be throwing that error if its being passed properly.

Comment: If you can, I would use SQL Profiler to look at the insert statement it is generating just to make sure what is going on.  This might help narrow things down, or at least confirm you are looking in the right place.

Comment: @JeffTreuting You were on the money! I updated the solution above to show the query. That query throws the error. EF is setting AccountSkillId as an Identity, which is causing it to be NULL because it is not set as an Identity in the DB

Comment: It would help if you could edit your question to add that in there as code so it is more easily readable.

Comment: @JeffTreuting thats what I did. The code itself is really oddly formatted and the code blocks did not enjoy it at all, but its up there in an update. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per this question: [Cannot insert the value NULL into column in ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727337/cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-in-asp-net-mvc-entity-framework)

The answer came down to adding `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` to my Entity runs like a charm. Huge shout out to @JeffTreuting for pointing me in the right direction with the SQL Trace. I honestly hadn't even thought about that. Thanks again everyone!

```
    public class lp_Skill
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long AccountSkillId { get; set; }

    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Rel { get; set; }
    public string Href { get; set; }
}
```