# Trouble editing the role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, roles

I am having a problem in editing the role of a user. I have these codes:

```
    `    
 Entities db2 = new Entities();
        private UsersContext db = new UsersContext();

   //
            // POST: /AdminOnly/Edit/5
             [Authorize(Roles = "Owner")]
            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Edit(UserProfile userprofile, int? roless)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    webpages_UsersInRoles s = new webpages_UsersInRoles();

                    s = db2.webpages_UsersInRoles.Where(m => m.UserId == userprofile.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (s != null) //with existing role, edit it
                    {
                        s.RoleId = roless.Value;
                        db.Entry(userprofile).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        db2.Entry(s).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        db2.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    else //no existing role
                    {
                       //some code here

                    }
                }
                ViewBag.roless = new SelectList(db2.webpages_Roles, "RoleId", "RoleName");
                return View(userprofile);
            }
    `
```

When I try to save the changes in the database,  `db2.SaveChanges();` throws me an error that says:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The property 'RoleId' is part of the object's
>   key information and cannot be modified.

What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the column I want to change is a compound foreign key. I need to remove the first value of the `RoleId` and save the changes to the table. And add again the second value and save the new changes to the table. Thanks to those who helped!

Answer (score 0):

RoleId is used as key constraint and main identifier of entity. You can't change this id. Just don't update this property or add more comments why do you need to update it.

Comment: Because I was required that role of the user can be changed (eg from Admin to Member). Basically upgrading/downgrading of roles.

Comment: Exactly. You want to change _this_ role. And how in future you can tell that you changed _this_ role? You should have some sort of identifier, so you'll be able to track what roles do you change. If you want to change the role, you can update other properties (except RoleId).

Comment: Adding a new ID perhaps?

Comment: You mean adding a new role? You can use db.Roles.Add(new Role { Prop1 = "something", Prop2 = "blabla" }); syntax.

Comment: Nope. I read somewhere here in StackOverflow that I can add an ID to the webpages_usersinrole table that will somehow be the primary key of the table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470736/cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-roleid-mvc4-simple-membership can this work on my problem?

Comment: This ID is usually automatically generated by database when entity is created. So you can't "add it" or update it. You can add an entity (role in your case) and new id will be generated for you from the database, according to database rules.

Comment: What if I create a new column named 'OldRoleId'?

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that RoleId is part of the primary key and cannot be changed.  Instead of editing the existing row in webpages_UsersInRoles, try deleting that row and adding a new one with the new RoleId value.

Comment: So I should add a new row in the webpages_UsersInRoles?

Comment: @bampie that's what I would recommend.  Delete the current relationship row and add a new one.

Comment: But the RoleID is an FK to an another table. Is it okay to delete it?

Comment: Yes.  You're telling the system that this User is no longer related to this Role, so removing that role is the same as removing that relationship.

Comment: So to sum it up, I will drop the column 'RoleID' and create a new 'RoleId' column?

Comment: No, no.  Don't drop the column RowId.  Delete the row where the RoleId equals the old role's ID and the User's ID equals the current user's ID.

Comment: So I will create a new column?